# Use application loader to upload Mac OS X binaries to itunesconnect?

Tags: macos, upload, binary

I added a new application for the new Mac OS X app store and the status is "waiting for upload", but when I launch the application loader it tells me "No eligible applications were found". I have ensured I am using the correct itunesconnect login by running the setup wizard from the application loader menu, but it still tells me I do not have any eligible applications for upload. Do I use the application loader to upload Mac OS X binaries? or is that just for ios applications?

Answer (score 1):

This is a step by step explanation by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/submission/

Otherwise use my small turtorial:
You have to add an application entry:

1. https://itunesconnect.apple.com
2. Goto "Manage Your Applications"
3. Then click the blue button "Add new App"
4. Select "Mac OS X App" (if it is not available you need to buy the membership)
5. Fill in all required steps
6. Restart the Application Loader, your App will occur.

Check also this: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/documents/submitting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010572-CH16-SW5